# Переход по нужному url

Tags: javascript, html, url

registration.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
     <title>Authorization page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="loginForm" method="POST" action="controller">
      <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login"/>
      <br/>Login:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="login" value=""/>
      <br/>Password:<br/>
      <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
      </form></hr>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Переход на registration.html:

```
 <a class="page-scroll" onclick="location.href='html/test.html';">Sign in</a>
```

Отправка данных с формы осуществляется по url: http://localhost:8080/airline/html/controller

А нужно по url:  http://localhost:8080/airline/controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
     <title>Authorization page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="loginForm" method="POST" action="/airline/controller">
      <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login"/>
      <br/>Login:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="login" value=""/>
      <br/>Password:<br/>
      <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
      </form></hr>
  </body>
 </html>
```